# keyup eventListener and text input field

Tags: javascript, user-input, dom-events, keyboard-events

I have an `eventListener` on they `keyup` event of the key f for the whole document to perform a function `foo()`.

Everything works perfectly until I have to edit a text field. In particular, when I type the key f, the function `foo()` is executed, which is undesirable when my purpose was to type in the text field.

Is there anyway that I can bypass this `eventListener` so that I can type normally on the text field?

This is my code:

```
document.addEventListener("keyup", function(event){
event.preventDefault();
    if (event.keyCode === 70){
        foo();
    }
});


function foo(){
    console.log("Howdy world");
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<input type="text" 
    onkeydown="event.stopPropagation()" 
    onkeyup="event.stopPropagation()" 
    onkeypress="event.stopPropagation()">
```

So what `event.stopPropagation()` is doing here?

> The event.stopPropagation() method stops the bubbling og an event to the parent elements, preventing any event handlers from being executed.

Here, in your case, when you type the key `F`it will first fire the event listeners of the `input` element itself and then propagates the event to its parent elements. Now, since `document` is also an ancestor of `input`, its event listener is also fired.

To prevent this, use `event.stopPropagation()` whenever you interact with the input. In this case, the events are `onkeydown`, `onkeyup` & `onkeypressed`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `tagName` of the `activeElement` and don't execute your function if it equals `input` for example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
   <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="text" name="" id="">


    <script>
        document.addEventListener("keyup", function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            if (event.keyCode === 70 && document.activeElement.tagName !== 'INPUT') {
                foo();
            }
        });

        function foo() {
            console.log("Howdy world");
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```